# Navbar getting in the way of Image

Tags: css, html, mobile

My navbar seems to get in the way of my logo when on mobile, it just climbs over it. how would I get it to not interfere with the image? It just kind of envelops it.

```css
.drp {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%
}
.lg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lg">
  <img src="12.png" width="100%" />
</div>
</div>
<body>
<div class="drp">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">
        <li>link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>link</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>link</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</div>
```

Comment: On a side note: You have a ending `body` tag before the opening of `drp`. Was it intentional?

Comment: Not at all. It was supposed to open, before, instead of close.

Comment: When I run your code snippet I don’t see the issue you are describing. Please revise your question. Either fix the code snippet or add a screenshot showing the problem.

Comment: Nope, you still need to use your `body` tag all the way up your content. Also please create the demo with a working image that shows your issue.

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-foWHOAW_2w4/VfOKBlzLgWI/AAAAAAAAcss/wQCZVe0PLpw/w952-h1692-no/Screenshot_2015-09-11-19-11-16.png How it looks on mobile

Comment: The problem is that the links are on top of the image?

Comment: Yes, they come over image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the `position: absolute` and `position: fixed` on `lg` and `drp` classes which makes them out of the normal flow of document.

I have a CSS hack for your current code. Your code works fine until the browser width is reduced to 600px. So try to modify your CSS within a media query, give both the classes `position: relative` and adjust the position of `lg` accordingly.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .lg {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    margin-top: 30px; /* top seems to not work sometimes when resizing, fiddle with the margin values */
  }

  .drp {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

**Screenshot after modifying:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I was hoping for something less hacky and more permanent. I don't mind redoing the whole thing, but I'd like it to for sure work. I'll appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Then you can use a Responsive framework like Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: There is a custom template for a site like yours: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ Sticky footer!